# Run elasticsearch script over all documents without sub bucketing

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-painless

Is it possible to run an elastic query with a painless script that returns a single bucket map that is the result of aggregating over all the documents in my index.

Comment: Yes, with the [`scripted_metric` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) which you can use to code your own aggregation logic. But beware of the performance depending on the size of your index.

Comment: Thank you! It looks promising

Comment: Just to update, that was the solution, worked great though I agree that it is very likely this will cause issues on larger indices so I will be looking into alternative forms of writing my data to query without requiring the script. Thanks again!

Comment: Just posted an answer since that can help others

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the [`scripted_metric` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) which you can use to code your own aggregation logic. But beware of the performance depending on the size of your index.

Also beware of [my comment](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28946#issuecomment-858551616) on this open issue when running scripted_metric on big indexes.